# Deploy to App Service Environment

Tags: azure, azure-pipelines

I have an App Service Environment (ASE, load balanced private network variety) setup in Azure that is running fine. I would now like to use VSTS to deploy builds to the ASE, but cannot see any obvious way of doing this.

The ASE is in a Virtual Network with a VPN Gateway setup. Currently we use the VPN Gateway as a means of manually accessing the VPN and subsequently FTP'ing onto App Service and pushing out the updates.

Could this VPN gateway be used by VSTS to access the Virtual Network of the ASE and subsequently do a standard App Service deploy? Or is there another way?

Comment: It seems that there's no need to use VPN, since the VSTS services and Azure are available on the internet, they can be easily used by teams that are distributed across multiple locations, without having any additional cost of VPN and overheads of security.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. I really just want to know how to use VSTS deploy and app to an ILB ASE.

Comment: Could your Visual Network connect to VSTS? If so, you could install a build agent in your Virtual Network and when deploy choosing this agent not the Host build agent.

Comment: Yes, in fact this is what I've done in the end.